# Is there any way to implement 'Forgot password functionality" using Azure Ad Graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am new to Azure AD B2C, As Azure B2C provides various policies and user flows like sign in signup etc. We are using the same. For some reason, We are having thought to use graph API (change password) for forgot password functionality, In documentation we did not found any graph api for generating verification code/send verification code to email and graph api to verify the code. Is there any Azure AD graph api to achieve the same? or is there any work around for the same?

Comment: Hi @Vipul Patil. Did the below answer help you?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Yes, It helped. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD Graph API does support [setting of passwords for users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#reset-a-users-password--) but it doesn't manage the verification codes.

You must generate, send and validate the verification codes for yourself.